# How to animate a circular progress bar with indicator bar on iOS?

Tags: ios, animation

Has anyone had any experience in working on an animation like the one shown in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: I have worked on Gauge Chart of Google Charts which does similar work but with slightly different UI.  Have a look to see if this satisfies your need.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge

Comment: This would work for you with some customization : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/semi-circular-scale

Comment: Hey @kapsym thank you for your immediate reply. But I am looking the animation code in native iOS swift.

Comment: See if this works then https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sfgaugeview

Comment: @kapsym will look into this..thanks

Comment: try this  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/wmgaugeview

Comment: @VikashKumar will check the link thanks

Comment: @raki thanks will look into the same